# admin inline ManyToMany autocomplete_fields

Tags: python, django, admin

I want to add search for the `AcademicGroupInline` with using its `vk_chat` relation

```py
# models.py

class AcademicGroup(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(
        'user.Student',
    )
    vk_chat = models.OneToOneField(
        'Chat',
    )


class Chat(models.Model):
    owner_id = models.BigIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField()


# admin.py

class AcademicGroupInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AcademicGroup.students.through
    autocomplete_fields = (
        'vk_chat',
    )


@admin.register(Student)
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AcademicGroupInline]
```

But I've got an error in result:

```py
<class 'user.admin.AcademicGroupInline'>: (admin.E037) The value of 'autocomplete_fields[0]' refers to 'vk_chat', which is not an attribute of 'course.AcademicGroup_students'.
```

Comment: You must define search_fields on the related object’s ModelAdmin because the autocomplete search uses it.: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should register AcademicGroup model, as you did with Student, and add in `search_fields` attribute which should have `vk_chat` as value.

```
@admin.register(AcademicGroup )
class AcademicGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      ....
      search_fields = ['vk_chat']
```

Second, in your AcademicGroup model, you should add in your M2M field this parameter `related_name='academicgroups'` (you can name it as you want).

Third, in your AcademicGroupInline class, you should put `Student.AcademicGroup.through` in model field instead of `AcademicGroup.students.through` because i guess you want to list Acadamicgroups associated to student not the inverse.

Finally, in your `autocomplete_fields` you can put only attributes of the model created by `AcademicGroup.students.through`, so i suggest you to print those attributes using `print(model._meta.fields)` inside your `AcademicGroupInline` class (i think you will get `id`, `student` and `academicgroup`).
So, your `autocomplete_fields` should have `academicgroup` as a value.

```
class AcademicGroupInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Student.academicgroups.through
    autocomplete_fields = (
        'academicgroup',
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Achraf I've been waiting for this answer for a long time. It works perfectly

Comment: Glad to hear that !